# Generated Numbers under a constraint?

Tags: random, algorithm

Let's say I have five four dimensional vectors $p_i^\mu=(p_i^1,p_i^2,p_i^3,p_i^4)$ with $i=1,2,3,4,5$. Now, I want to fill the entries of these vectors ($4\cdot5=20$ in total) with some numbers, but such that the resulting vectors satisfy the following $9$ constraints:

$$(p_i^1)^2-(p_i^2)^2-(p_i^3)^2-(p_i^4)^2=0~~~\text{for each }i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$p_1^\mu+p_2^\mu+p_3^\mu+p_4^\mu+p_5^\mu=0~~~\text{for each }\mu\in\{1,2,3,4\}$$

What is a convenient way to create such constrained vectors in *Mathematica*?
Maybe there is a built in function that does just that?

Comment: You can't mean to include $\mu=0$.

Comment: If you do not like that the labels of the four dimensions for each vector start with $\mu=0$ and go to $\mu=3$ you are welcome to relabel them to $\mu\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. Actually, let me do that above, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I suppose you've at least a range for the coordinates values ...

Comment: Sure! Let's take each coordinate out of a box with length $-L<p<L$ and $L=$ your preferred non-zero real number.

Comment: Sounds more like a math / method problem than a Mathematica one. To my knowledge there isn't anything built-in for such general constraints. So, in other words you need 5 "light-like" vectors in Minkowski space that add up to zero, right?

Comment: Do you have the requirement that these vectors should be uniformly distributed, i.e. each solution to the constraints should be generated with equal probability, or do you just want "five arbitrary vectors that satisfy the constraints"?  If you do need a correct uniform distribution, then as belisarius said, you need to restrict your domain.  Do you accept any kind of restriction for the domain I can make up, or just this $L$-sized box?  Personally I don't like the box. :P A cylinder is easier.

Comment: Yes, I need 5 light-like vectors in Minkowski space, which add up to zero (so at least one with negative energy, but thats accounted for, so it is ok).
If you prefer a cylinder, you are welcome to take a cylinder. I need this just to test my analytic results numerically, so as long as the vectors are somewhat random I am happy.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Maybe you should remove random from the title in that case.  Generating truly uniformly distributed random numbers under general constraint like these seems to be far from a trivial problem, and the current title implies that this is what you want.

Comment: Ok, I edited the topic, now it is about some generated numbers, not necessarily random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** - general function, description at the end

```
ClearAll[LightlikeVectorsThatSumUpToZero];
LightlikeVectorsThatSumUpToZero[n_Integer: 5] := Module[
 {m, p, eq, set, sol, res, s = 4},
   While[
    m = Array[p, {n, s}];
    m[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n - 1, s - 1}];
    m[[2, 2]] = p[2, 2];

    (# = -Total[{##2}]) & @@@ Transpose[m][[3 ;;]];
    (# = Sqrt[{##2}.{##2}]) & @@@ m[[3 ;;]];

    eq = Join[(# == -Total[{##2}]) & @@@ Transpose[m][[ ;; 2]], 
              (#^2 == {##2}.{##2}) & @@@ m[[ ;; 2]]];
    set = Flatten[Array[p, {2, 2}], 1];
    sol = Quiet@NSolve[eq, set, Reals];
    Length[sol] == 0
    ,
    ClearAll[p, m];
    ];
   (res = m /. sol[[1]])
   ] /; n > 3

LightlikeVectorsThatSumUpToZero[7]
```

> ```
> {{-2.71877, 2.05619, 0.176773, 1.7699}, {-2.17312, -2.00133, -0.762688, -0.368013}, 
>  {1.18436, -0.346408, 0.618285, -0.948914}, {1.16035, -0.625387, 0.82161, 0.529396}, 
>  {0.99203, 0.339333, 0.329197, -0.872127}, {0.393379, -0.112851, -0.262639, -0.270245},
>  {1.16177, 0.69045, -0.920539, 0.160005}}
> ```

---

The following method is very strightforward. We are generating entries till the point there are as many unknowns as we can create quations. The we are using `NSolve` to get last.

With `RandomReal` it is highly unlikely we can get dependent vectors.

```
ClearAll[p, m]

(*1*) m = Array[p, {5, 4}];
      m[[ 2 ;;, 2 ;;]] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 3}];
(*2*) m[[ 2, 2]] = p[2, 2];

      (# = -Total[{##2}]) & @@@ Transpose[m][[ 3 ;;]];

      (# = Sqrt[{##2}.{##2}]) & @@@ m[[ 3 ;;]];
(*3*)

       eq = Join[
                 (# == -Total[{##2}]) & @@@ Transpose[m][[ ;; 2]],
                 (#^2 == {##2}.{##2}) & @@@ m[[ ;; 2]]
                ];
       set = Flatten[Array[p, {2, 2}], 1]; (*{p[1, 1], p[1, 2], p[2, 1], p[2, 2]}*)

       sol = NSolve[ eq, set, Reals];

       (res = m /. sol[[ 1]]); 
(*4*)

       (#^2 - {##2}.{##2}) & @@@ res // Chop
       Total /@ Transpose[res] // Chop
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> {0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

[image]

Comment: @rasher Thanks ;) It seems that sometimes system can't be solved so one may want to use `Check` or something and redo this.

Comment: Can it do more or less than 5 vectors also? My only problem with it is that I do not understand all the symbolic shortcut gibberish...

Comment: @Kagaratsch done.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is a really scetchy solution (up to numerical accuracy). It can compute the requested vectors not only in the case of 5 vectors, but for arbitrary number (set variable `point` to the desired value).

```
Remove["Global`*"]
point = 7;
SeedRandom;
rnd[x_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
mat = {};
Do[mat = Append[
 mat, {Subscript[p0, i], sg Subscript[p1, i], sg Subscript[p2, i],
   sg Subscript[p3, i]}];, {i, 1, point}];
vec = {};
Do[vec = Append[vec, 1];, {i, 1, point}];
vec1 = Diagonal[(mat /. sg -> 1).(Transpose[mat] /. sg -> -1)];
vec2 = Transpose[mat /. sg -> 1].vec;
vecf = vec1;
Do[vecf = Append[vecf, vec2[[i]]];, {i, 1, Length[vec2]}];
res = vecf - vecf;
now = 4 point - 4 - point;
now1 = now - point + 1;
If[now1 > -1, cnt3 = point - 1;, If[now > -1, cnt3 = now, cnt3 = 0]];
now = now1;
now1 = now - point + 1;
If[now1 > -1, cnt2 = point - 1;, If[now > -1, cnt2 = now, cnt2 = 0]];
now = now1;
now1 = now - point + 1;
If[now1 > -1, cnt1 = point - 1;, If[now > -1, cnt1 = now, cnt1 = 0]];
sol = mat[[All, 1]];
Do[Subscript[p3, i] = rnd[1];, {i, 1, cnt3}];
Do[sol = Append[sol, Subscript[p3, i]], {i, cnt3 + 1, point}];
Do[Subscript[p2, i] = rnd[1];, {i, 1, cnt2}]; 
Do[sol = Append[sol, Subscript[p2, i]], {i, cnt2 + 1, point}];
Do[Subscript[p1, i] = rnd[1];, {i, 1, cnt1}];
Do[sol = Append[sol, Subscript[p1, i]], {i, cnt1 + 1, point}];
sub = FindInstance[vecf == res, sol, Reals][[1]];
Do[Subscript[p0, i] = Subscript[p0, i] /. sub; 
   Subscript[p1, i] = Subscript[p1, i] /. sub; 
   Subscript[p2, i] = Subscript[p2, i] /. sub; 
   Subscript[p3, i] = Subscript[p3, i] /. sub;, {i, 1, point}];
```

The variable `vecf` containes all the constraints. After the solution has been found all the entries of `vecf` are properly numerically zero.